# Rust function that returns different type of value depending on type annotation

Tags: rust

I want to have function that returns different type of value depending on type annotation, something like:

```
give_five::<String>(); // returns "five"
give_five::<i32>(); // returns 5
give_five::<f32>(); // return 5.0
```

I tried to write but it doesn't work. I know why it doesn't work. But I have no clue how to do it.

```
fn give_five<String>() -> String {
    String::from("five")
}
fn give_five<i32>() -> i32 {
    5
}
fn give_five<f32>() -> f32 {
    5.0
}
```

I got the idea from `rand` crate. Since it can do

```
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
let x: i32 = rng.gen();
let y: f32 = rng.gen();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done by defining a trait:

```
trait GiveFive {
    fn give_five() -> Self;
}
```

and implementing it for the types you want:

```
impl GiveFive for &'static str {
    fn give_five() -> &'static str {
        return "five";
    }
}

impl GiveFive for i32 {
    fn give_five() -> i32 {
        return 5;
    }
}

impl GiveFive for f32 {
    fn give_five() -> f32 {
        return 5.0;
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
fn main() {
    let x: &str = GiveFive::give_five(); // returns "five"
    let y: i32 = GiveFive::give_five(); // returns 5
    let z: f32 = GiveFive::give_five(); // return 5.0
}
```

or

```
fn main() {
    let x = <&str>::give_five(); // returns "five"
    let y = i32::give_five(); // returns 5
    let z = f32::give_five(); // return 5.0
}
```